# when to use a Vforce page on a standard object

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects, isv

We have a client using vforce pages on the standard objects for Lead, Account and Contact. Our application is failing on these vforce pages. I asked the client why they are using a vforce page, and they say they do not remember, but are unwilling to revery back to the standard object.

Why would an org use a vforce page vs the standard objects? Anyone have any experience here?

Answer (score 5):

The only reason to do this is when you need to add some extra, custom functionality.

In this case you need to determine whey they did this in the first place; ask them to provide the page code (if you don't have access to it) so that you can see what's in there. If it's little more than an `<apex:detail>` tag then they probably don't need it. Otherwise, if you've got the source you might be able to work out what causes your app to take issue with those pages and find a workaround on your end.

Answer (score 3):

Its all about a custom or branded user experience.

We've done a full Visualforce makeover for a customer in the past as they had a corporate brand that they were adamant had to apply to every page a user could see. Menus and tabs had to be moved around the page, and you just can't do that using the standard user interface configuration options.

Another reason might be because they needed a highly guided way to interact with these records - wizard based creation, for example - if the work was done prior to visual flow going GA, Visualforce was pretty much the only option.

The final reason that a company might end up in this situation is choosing the wrong person/company for the implementation - a lot of people come to Salesforce from Java/.Net and assume that the best solution for everything is to write Visualforce and Apex.

Its interesting that they can't remember why they went Visualforce - I'd expect this to be obvious from accessing the pages.  They would have spent a fair amount of money to override the standard functionality this way, as well as the ongoing maintenance costs, so I'd expect there to be a good reason for it, and for it to be providing a significant benefit. Unless its because of the final reason above!

Comment: I suspect its your final reason, and now no-one wants to undo this. The Customer has over 1000 users.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a VF page only if there is some functionality which cannot be achieved using standard layouts and standard methods and triggers.

For eg allow editing of multiple records in one page, or business requires you to enter a field before you enter others and based on the entry prepopulate certain fields, the needs could be anything, if its not achievable using standard pages then use VF page